# size on disk of pickled objects

Tags: python, pickle

I want to serialize an object (which contains other objects etc) and I would like to exclude (if possible) attributes that take up a lot space when the pickle file is saved on the disk. I plan to do this by deleting the attribute while manipulating `__getstate__(self)` of my (top level) class, for example:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    attr = self.__dict__.copy()
    del attr['some_key'].some_other.key
    return attr
```

Is there a way to determine how much space each attribute occupies. I dont necessarily want to do it on the fly. Saving a full pickle once and then interrogate it to see which keys are the heaviest so I know how to edit my `__getstate__()` would be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to actually dump it.

```py
import pickle

PICKLE_SIZE_LIMIT = 32  # in bytes


class Foo:
    def __getstate__(self):
        # Dump v into bytes and include only if it is less than the limit size.
        return {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if len(pickle.dumps(v)) < PICKLE_SIZE_LIMIT}
```

Note that you have to take into account the size of the pickle header to get the exact size. However, if I understand correctly, all you want to know is whether it is large enough or not, so you should be able to ignore it.